# Annoying spaces that won't disappear. What should I do?

Tags: python, string, text, colorama

I am currently making a game with Python.

I want the code to read:

```
[00:00:00]   Name|Hello!
```

Here is my code:

```
print(Fore.YELLOW + Style.BRIGHT + '['),
print strftime("%H:%M:%S"),
print ']',
print(Style.BRIGHT + Fore.RED + ' Name'),
print(Fore.BLACK + '|'),
print(Fore.WHITE + Style.DIM + 'Hello!')
time.sleep(5)
```

Instead - for some reason - it becomes like this:

```
[ 00:00:00 ]    Name | Hello!
```

I have no idea what's wrong with this code, or how to fix it.

I would really appreciate all the help I can get! Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Printing with a single `print` statement and a comma always prints a trailing space.

Either use *one* print statement with everything concatenated, or use `sys.stdout.write()` to write to the terminal directly without the extra spaces:

```
print Fore.YELLOW + Style.BRIGHT + '[' + strftime("%H:%M:%S") + ']',
```

or

```
sys.stdout.write(Fore.YELLOW + Style.BRIGHT + '[')
sys.stdout.write(strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
sys.stdout.write(']')
```

or use string formatting:

```
print '{Fore.YELLOW}{Style.BRIGHT}[{time}] {Style.BRIGHT}{Fore.RED} Name {Fore.BLACK}| {Fore.WHITE}{Style.DIM}Hello!'.format(
    Style=Style, Fore=Fore, time=strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use the `end=""` option to print().  This prints no linefeed and also does not add the extra space at the end.

```
print(Style.BRIGHT + Fore.RED + ' Name', end="")
print(Fore.BLACK + '|', end="")
print(Fore.WHITE + Style.DIM + 'Hello!')
```

The caveat being that the `end` option is only available with Python 3.  It's also available in Python 2.6-ish if you `from __future__ import print_function`